# Importing Google Maps API JS file with React

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, create-react-app

I'm trying to integrate the polygon containsLocation function into my react app. This currently appears to only be supported by the actual JS library imported with the maps.googleapis.com script tag added. That being said, I keep getting the no-undef error when attempting to use the maps.Polygon constructor (I'm currently using create-react-app with the default settings). Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

Code causing the issue:

```
var addedPoly = {
     polygon: maps.Polygon({
                            paths: parsedCoords
                        })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create-react-app` uses [Eslint](https://eslint.org) in order to lint your code. Given you've included  the google maps library through a script tag, it is available globally, while create-react-app (with its eslint configuration) doesn't expect globals, unless they are declared as such.

You can see in [eslint documentation the no-undef error](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef)

There are a couple of choices to fix this issue. First, if it is global, it will be available through window variable.

```
const maps = window.maps;
```

That way, it becomes a local variable.

Otherwise, you could add a .eslintrc file (if it does not exist already), where you set maps as global

```
"globals": {
    "maps": true
}
```

last, but not least, you could add at the top of your file the following comment

```
/*global maps*/
```

which will also work.

The advantage of the second option over the others is that you only need to implement it once, the other two options imply changes in each file where `maps` is used. It is up to you